# Fork in critical section

Tags: linux, fork, critical-section

Recently, in an interview I gave, we were discussing about the critical sections.
The question asked was "`what happens when we execute fork inside critical section? Will the resulting child process also execute the critical section simultaneously?`"
We discussed about the possibilities though:

1. Yes, both might execute the critical section simultaneously
2. fork() system call might be blocking for child process, allowing only parent to execute the critical section.
3. Compiler may be intelligent enough to identify this problem and might throw compilation error.
   Unfortunately, I could not find more details about this on the internet. TIA.

Edited:
Adding the pseudocode for reference:

```
semaphore s;
s.wait(); // lock
/* critical-section */
pid = fork(); /* what will happen here in child/parent process? */
s.signal(); // unlock
```

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on the semaphore implementation?

Comment: There are different things called "semaphores" with different semantics.  POSIX semaphores, SysV semaphores, something handwritten?

Answer (score 1):

For Linux semaphores, the second parameter of `sem_init` determines if it's a cross-process semaphore. You place those in shared memory, which is inherited by `fork`.

`fork` does not try to check existing semaphores, nor does it try to adjust the semaphore count. Semaphores can have counts >1, and will allow that many running threads. So a count of 2 would allow two threads to run - `fork` isn't going to guess.

[edit] The old answer below assumed a Linux futex, which is more like a critical section.

"The" critical section is misleading. After the fork, both processes have their own critical sections. As a result, none of your 3 options apply.

Comment: Ok. By "critical section", I mean a set of code protected by semaphore.
Imagine that:
semaphore s;
s.wait();
// critical section code or a resource
pid = fork();
s.signal();

Now that while replying the above, I think there will be a different semaphore altogether and thereby, different copy of the critical section? I am not able to think clearly. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> what happens when we execute fork inside critical section? Will the resulting child process also execute the critical section simultaneously?"
>
> 1. Yes, both might execute the critical section simultaneously
> 2. fork() system call might be blocking for child process, allowing only parent to execute the critical section.
> 3. Compiler may be intelligent enough to identify this problem and might throw compilation error. Unfortunately, I could not find more
>    details about this on the internet. TIA.

Any of those and more is possible in principle, but neither (2) nor (3) is implemented by any system I know.  In particular, since you tagged Linux, GLibc's `fork()` doesn't have any special provision for interaction with semaphores, and GCC will not reject code on the grounds you suggest. (There is a matter of the (System V)  semaphore adjustment, but that's not directly relevant.)

But (1) is not completely correct, either.  It is true that if the `fork()` is successful then the child will start execution by returning from the fork into the critical section.  Nothing specifically prevents that from happening while the parent is still inside the critical section itself, so it *may* be that both run in the critical section at the same time.  On the other hand, it is possible that one of the two resulting processes does not get scheduled to actually execute any instructions until a time that happens to be after the other has exited the critical section.  That would look a lot like (2) even though technically, neither process was blocked.

That is barely the tip of the iceberg of issues involved in such a situation, however.